# Trying to read a 12 byte hex string (RFID tag ID) using SerialPort Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I'm trying to make an application that can read a 12 byte hex string from the serial port and display it into a text box, the source is a RFID module that is connected to my USB port using a RS232-USB converter.

My first problem was accessing the text box in the datarecieved event due to invalid cross-threaded operation. Upon googling that, I copy/pasted the code I needed to get it work, these are all the cross threading functions.

The OpenPort function and Datarecieved event are my own code, the rest I got off google.

The application then worked, but I would get an incomplete code, the first swipe I would get all 12 digits, and at every other swipe, the first byte would vanish. Upon some more reading, I decided to make an array, the size of the incoming data (shown in the code below), but now I get the cross-threading error again.

I know there's something wrong with the way I'm using the array. This is way beyond my VB knowledge, and I'm in over my head here, could use some expert help. I'm an electronics engineer and self taught myself a little programming to create some apps for my hardware.

Thanks.

Updated code:

```
Public Class Form3
    Dim msg As String

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            lstPorts.Items.Add(s)
        Next s

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If lstPorts.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a port")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
            SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
            SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            SerialPort1.PortName = lstPorts.SelectedItem.ToString
            SerialPort1.Open()
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived

        msg = SerialPort1.ReadExisting


        Me.Invoke(New Action(
        Sub()
            txtReceived.Clear()
            txtReceived.Text += msg
        End Sub))

    End Sub



    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        txtReceived.Text = ""
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you read here:

```
If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
   msg = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()         
End If
```

You will lose when you overwrite it here:

```
msg = enc.GetString(bytesarray)
```

I don't generally recommend trying to read strings directly from serial ports (or TCP/IP connections either for that matter).  Stick with the array approach only and get rid of ReadExisting.  Only when you know you have a whole "message" would I convert the bytes to a string.

Some generic tips (though this varies by protocol):

1. Define a buffer to read your messages into that is large enough to hold your entire message, and don't make it a local variable.
2. Keep track of the offset into that buffer.
3. When you first read, your offset will be 0 and lets say you read 2 bytes.  Your offset will then be +2 for a value of 1.
4. Upon your second (and third, etc) read you insert starting at that offset, effectively appending the new bytes.
5. After each read you must inspect your buffer to see if you have received a whole message.  You can do this by the total amount read (if you have fixed-length messages), or by some info in thebuffer (like a length prefix).  Once you read your message you need to remove it from the buffer.
6. I suggest starting with a simple approach and after removing the message you reset your offset back to zero and continue the process.  If the data you had received was LONGER than the message you had removed, you need to shift those extra bytes to the "left" so that they start at position 0.  (A more efficient approach is to use a circular buffer, but KISS for now).

---

In your DataRecv event you should do something like this to update your UI:

```
   Me.Invoke(New Action(
      Sub()
         'this code runs on the GUI thread, update textboxes!
         Me.Text += msg
      End Sub))
```

---

I'm still not a fan of ReadExisting, but if you are sure you are always getting prinatble characters out of your device then try something like this:

```
Public Class Form3 

    Private pendingMsg As New StringBuffer()

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
        For Each s In System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() 
            lstPorts.Items.Add(s) 
        Next s 

    End Sub 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
        If lstPorts.SelectedIndex = -1 Then 
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a port") 
            Exit Sub 
        Else 
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600 
            SerialPort1.DataBits = 8 
            SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None 
            SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One 
            SerialPort1.PortName = lstPorts.SelectedItem.ToString 
            SerialPort1.Open() 
        End If 
    End Sub 


    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived 

        Dim completedMsg As String
        completedMsg = String.Empty

        pendingMsg.Append(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())

        If pendingMsg.Length >= 24 Then '12 bytes in hex is 24 chars

           completedMsg = pendingMsg.ToString(0, 24) '1st 24 bytes are a msg

           pendingMsg.Remove(0, 24) 'pop off the msg from our buffer

           Me.Invoke(New Action( 
           Sub()                
               txtReceived.Text = completedMsg                               
           End Sub)) 

        End If

    End Sub 


    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
        SerialPort1.Close() 
        txtReceived.Text = "" 
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: I've been testing with both ReadExisting and Read. When I disable the If statement with Readexisting, I get a corss-threading error, and when I disable the array, I get incomplete data.

Comment: I found this code: vbdotnet.com.nu/receiving_text_with_a_delegate.html - it works great, just one problem, it appends the textbox every time I swipe the card. I've tried placing a txtRecieved.text = "" everywhere, it messes the whole thing up. I need the textbox refresh and reprint the data in it whenever I swipe. Like in my original code - Could someone please tell me where/what I can do to prevent the textbox from appending the next data received.

Comment: No offense, but you've got lots of other junk in that code that isn't doing anything useful.  Like launcing a thread to add a textbox to a form and then aborting the thread?  All of that stuff needs to get removed.  You should be creating the SerialPort, listening for the event, and handling the event.  No explicit threads are needed.

Comment: Yeah, I know lol, as I stated above I just coped/pasted that from various sources as I google'd for errors. I've got absolutely no idea how delegates work - Although I did get a similar code for a serial data reader (link in my previous comment) which works, I just need it to stop appending the textbox. Which, I cant figure out how to do. If it can stop appending the new data in the textbox everytime I swipe my tag across my RFID module, I'll be good to go. - Thanks

Comment: OK, nix the threads like I said.  You should just have your Open code and your event handler and that is it.  I added code that lets you update the UI from the DataRcvd event (which comes in on a different thread, hence the errors you used to get)

Comment: Updated the code in my OP according to your suggestions, it works, but when I used txtReceived.Clear(), it jumbles up the data. THe first swipe is fine, but the next swipes give me incomplete data, sometimes just 1 byte.

Comment: Take a look at the new edit.  Note that it requires that 24 hex chars to have been read before it will show the message.  The concern is what if the device only gives you 6 and then the cable is yanked.  In a production environment you would need to use timeouts and the like to deal with data underrun and overrun.